# How can the new vb.net application instance opened without closing the old vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net

We have some vb.net application running in the server. We are using windows server 2012 R2 server .Server and clients are connected through LAN and clients will be accessing application from server and all clients access from same path .When new version of application is built the changes will be  directly replaced  in server  with clients working on vb.net instance .With old  application instance open ,when we try to open new application instance it opens old application instead of new .How can the  new vb.net application instance opened without closing the old vb.net application?
We are using visual studio 2008 and clients can be with operating system windows XP,7,8.

Comment: what is the point of doing all this? keeping the old version open while opening the new one??

Comment: I dont see how you could update a file that is in use

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the embedded `ClickOnce Deployment` Publish and Deploy feature? It's in Visual Studio 2008.

You can update your program, deploy it on the server, and force every application (installed on your network client PCs) to check for updated at the next launch. It's very simple to do, it's just a yes/no check during the deployment phase.

Comment: Is click one deployment and Publish and Deploy same?

Comment: @ITresearcher yes, ClickOnce Deployment